# I cannot figure out why the alert is not showing the this.state.word string

Tags: reactjs, forms, firebase

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      word: '',
      isSignedIn: false
    }
  }

    ..........................................

  newsChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      word: event.target.value
    })
  }


  submit = (event) => {
    alert(`this ${this.state.word}`)
    // db.collection("news").add({
    // Mnews: this.state.word})}

  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isSignedIn) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>unsure if google link works</h1>
          <p>Please sign-in:</p>
          <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>HI</h1>
        <p>Welcome {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}! You are now signed-in!</p>


        <a onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>Sign-out</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <label >Latest news (text only)</label>
          <hr />
          <input type="text"
            vlaue={this.state.word}
            onChange={this.state.newsChange} />
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>


        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginPage;
```

The alert pops up with "undefined" if i place another variable in the box but if it has the correct variable it pops up with nothing, instead of what should be reflected in the form.

The aim is to add the data into the firestore.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your input `vlaue`, you also need to call this newsChange. Not this.state.newsChange.

```
<input type="text" 
  value= {this.state.word}
  onChange={this.newsChange}/>
```

Comment: thanks, i am actually partially blind so that helped a lot more than it should have :/

i also addd state to the fuinction by accident

Comment: If you're interested, adding some linting to your project and editor might make it easier to spot these kind of issues in the future. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

You spelled value wrong and onChange should not come from this.state.newsChange but from this.newsChange and you should prevent default if you don't want the form to submit.

```js
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    word: '',
    isSignedIn: false
  }

  newsChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      word: event.target.value
    })
  }

  submit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(`this ${this.state.word}`)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.word}
            onChange={this.newsChange}
          />
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



//render app
ReactDOM.render(<LoginPage />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```